# Why none other than the c1 variable (c2,c3,c4 and c5) getting the data

Tags: php

i wanted to retrive a piece of python code from the database.

The javascript variable c1 is working properly but the following c2,c3,c4 and c5 is not showing the data wheres all the php variables are showing the data properly.

What might be the reason and what can be the solution?

I have tried to use javascript and php togather to get the desired result as I am going to pass the variables on a javascript function. php variables are showing the data but the javascript variable c1 is getting the data but c2,c3,c4 and c5 are not getting the data

```
  echo "<script> var c1 = '".$code_1."';  </script>";
  echo "<script> var c2 = '".$code_2."';  </script>";
  echo "<script> var c3 = '".$code_3."';  </script>";
  echo "<script> var c4 = '".$code_4."';  </script>";
  echo "<script> var c5 = '".$code_5."';  </script>";

  // c1 works properly

  echo "<script>alert(c1);</script>";

  // c2,c3,c4,c5 doesn't works

  echo "<script>alert(c2);</script>";
```

Comment: Look at your resulting HTML, and look at your browser console for errors.

Comment: it's saying c2 is not defined

Comment: So, what does that tell you?

Comment: but why is it saying that? then it should also show c1 is not defined

Comment: As I already said, look at your HTML.

Comment: haven't found any issues in my html

Comment: What do you see when you use `View Source`?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but why are you creating a separate `<script>` tag for each statement?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: It's generally safer to write `echo "<script> var c1 = ".json_encode($code_1).";  </script>";`. That will ensure that special characters are escaped properly.

Comment: Were there special characters in `c2` that caused errors?

Comment: it was a part of a python code that i needed to retrieve from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to properly format any special characters in the PHP values, rather than just substituting the PHP values directly into JS.

```
  echo "<script> var c1 = ".json_encode($code_1).";  </script>";
  echo "<script> var c2 = ".json_encode($code_2).";  </script>";
  echo "<script> var c3 = ".json_encode($code_3).";  </script>";
  echo "<script> var c4 = ".json_encode($code_4).";  </script>";
  echo "<script> var c5 = ".json_encode($code_5).";  </script>";
```